# Datatypes usage convention

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I see different ways to use datatypes in spark - https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datatypes.html.

For instance, array of string can be represented as `ArrayType(StringType())` or `array<string>`. What is the difference between these to naming? I understand as per the doc that , ArrayType(StringType())  is dataframe type and array is for Python. Can we use one replacing other?

```
# first approach
StructField("col_name", ArrayType(StringType()))

# another approach
.withColumn("col_name",from_json(col("col_name"), "array<string>"))
```

Comment: both approaches are allowed. It's just different way of specifying things. You can specify columns as normal strings `"colname"` or as `F.col("colname")`. There are many ways to do the same thing. If you are in doubt, you can print out the `df.explain()` to see if they are same or not.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR** 
Both are same, the former is often used when defining a schema, and the latter is used directly in SQL expressions.

Both represent an array data type where each element is of type string. However, they are specified using different syntax depending on the context.

**ArrayType(StringType()):**

This is typically used in the context of defining a schema for a StructType. For example, when creating a DataFrame with a schema, you might use this syntax to define an array column with string elements.

```
schema = StructType([
   StructField("col_name", StringType(), True),
   StructField("col_names", ArrayType(StringType()), True)
])
```

**array:**

This syntax is commonly used in SQL expressions when working with Spark SQL. It's a shorthand notation for creating an array with string elements directly in a SQL expression.

```
SELECT array('col_name1', 'col_name2', 'col_name3') AS columns;
```